# How can I sum the last 5 values from the bottom from column J or K for a certain team in either column B or C?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is my table that I've been using, it is much bigger than this, but this the max that fits in the pic

[image] I want to sum the teams forms, but I don't how to include two columns, because I already got help on how to do for only one column. For example, if I only want to sum the Home results or the Away results, but what if I want to find the last 5 games from a certain team whether they played at home or away? This is what I struggle with.

I tried using `SUMPRODUCT` and `AGGREGATE`, but it just showed #REF!, I must have done something poorly.

Comment: There is no picture. Even if there was, no-one is going to type data in from a picture. Put a sample table into the body of your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question is a little unclear, what you mean by last 5 games - the 5 most recent games by date? The last 5 on the list (in case the list is not always sorted)? Last 5 games that include the specific team? But I believe this is what you are after:

```
=LET(TOPFIVE,TAKE(SORT(FILTER($A$1:$K$20,($B$1:$B$20=M2)+($C$1:$C$20=M2))),-5),
SUMPRODUCT(--(CHOOSECOLS(TOPFIVE,2,3)=M2)*(CHOOSECOLS(TOPFIVE,10,11))))
```

`FILTER` to filter the list to only include games where the specified team played home or away.

`SORT` and `TAKE` to get the 5 most recent games by date from the filtered list.

`SUMPRODUCT` the Home and Away columns (2 and 3) by the Home_PTS and Away_PTS columns (10 and 11).

[image]

Comment: Sorry for not making my problem clear, I am fairly new here and still trying to learn. Thank you for your advice and help, it was helpful!